# Form data comes null in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms

i don't understand why my form data comes null, someone can help me please ?

Contorller (CartesController.php):

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
  $carte = new Cartes();
  dd(request('numero')); // null 
}
```

Route (web.php):

```
Route::post('/addcartes', 'CartesController@store');
```

Form (addcartesview.blade.php):

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-xl-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Ajouter une carte : </div>
            <div class="card-body">

            <form method="post" action="./addcartes">
            {{ csrf_field() }}

<label for="numero">Numero</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="numero" placeholder="Numero" >
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Card</button>
</form>

</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
@endsection}
```

Comment: Your input has no name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is wrong. it is not

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="numero" placeholder="Numero" >
```

It should be

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="numero" placeholder="Numero" name="numero" >
```

Your controller is wrong. it is not

```
dd(request('numero'));
```

It should be

```
dd($request->input('numero'));
```

If you want to print  out all request for debugging you should use

```
dd($request->all());
```

Read more about Laravel request [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests).

Answer (score 1):

add name attribute on input tag

Answer (score 0):

Check your action and try dd($request->all());